# GetClipboardData on a delay rendered data inside a clipboard viewer causes recursive WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD

Tags: winapi, clipboard

When some other program puts a delay rendered data to clipboard (by calling SetClipboardData(fmt, NULL)), my clipboard viewer gets WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD.
When my viewer calls GetClipboardData(), my window proc is called recursively with another WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD.
I can't find any description of that.

```
#define MY_CF CF_RIFF

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
            OpenClipboard(hwnd);
            HGLOBAL hglob = GetClipboardData(MY_CF); // Sends recursive WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't handle `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` properly you should let the message forward to other windows

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
>   Each window that receives the WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD message must call the
>   SendMessage function to pass the message on to the next window in the
>   clipboard viewer chain. The handle to the next window in the chain is
>   returned by SetClipboardViewer, and may change in response to a
>   WM_CHANGECBCHAIN message.

Second, unfortunately receiving many `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` is common. By experience it's common to receive between 0 and 4. 
 The ugly trick (which works) is to get timestamps on each call, and if it's too close to the previous one simply ignore.

Comment: Or (re)start a short timer on each message, and when the timer elapses then assume the clipboard contents have stabilized.

Comment: "First, you don't handle WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD properly" I removed a lot of code from the sample

Comment: I use a global flag to check for recursion

Comment: SetClipboardViewer() also calls the window proc and If I get clipboard data inside it, SetClipboardViewer() fails

Comment: @basin if the function failure is handled and nothing is solved try with the timer approach. Be sure to unlock clipboard before forwarding messages.