# Figuring out if current clipboard data is rendered delayed

Tags: c#, clipboard

I'm currently working on a clipboard monitor/history. As of now it works pretty well, but I'm concerned about clipboard data using *delayed rendering*. I would like to just ignore those, but I can't seem to figure out if the current data in the clipboard is rendered delayed.

I already checked [`user32.dll` clipboard functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468802(v=vs.85).aspx), but it doesn't seem I can use one of those.

Is there a way to figure out, if the data is rendered delayed?

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895865/getclipboarddata-on-a-delay-rendered-data-inside-a-clipboard-viewer-causes-recur) help you?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm already handling `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` as this message is always sent when the clipboard is changed. But it doesn't help me figuring out if it's rendered delayed.

Comment: Why does it matter if it's rendered delayed?

Comment: It was an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2579846/2352031) to another question that I stumbled upon, that made me concerned about this

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no public API that exposes this information.